# Загрузка обложки музыки из интернета в плеер

Tags: c#, winforms

Добавляю композиции в `listBox` и воспроизвожу благодаря функциям `WindowsMediaPlayer`, хотя он скрыт и вместо него визуально используются другие компоненты. Нужно чтобы когда пользователь нажимал `button` воспроизведения программа искала по названию композиции в Google Картинках обложку альбома и загружала первую попавшуюся в `pictureBox`. Если включить другую композицию, то загрузится соответствующая ей обложка.

Comment: И в чём проблема? Что вы сделали для этого уже и что не получилось?

Comment: Не знаю как реализовать. Было несколько идей , но все ерунда. Надеюсь может кто подскажет направление.

Comment: Ну, на SO есть например такой вариант - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34035422